# How to debug Pig being stuck after job submission

Tags: apache-pig, elastic-map-reduce

I have a map-reduce job written in Pig that is doing the following.

Given a set of apache log files representing visits to a certain resource on a website

- clean the logs from the robots and from the unwanted log lines
- produce the tuples (ip, resource_id) found in the logs

For example this log:
`1.1.1.1 - [14/Jun/2014:06:26:27 +0000] "GET /path/to/resource/<resource_id>" "Agent"`

will be transalted into (if it's not a robot):
`(1.1.1.1, <resource_id>)`

This is done with a simple UDF that parse the log with a regex + a library for robot detection.
Starting from this step the script continues with a couple of additional map-reduce operations.

The issue is the following:

- I am able to complete the pig job locally.
- I uploaded the script to Amazon Elastic Map Reduce with 5GB of logs to be processed.
- I ran the script for 1 hours with 10 `m1.large` instances.
- The job didn't finished and I terminated it.

The hadoop logs that have been produced does not show much progress and seems to be stuck in the initial preparation phase described previously.

`2014-07-07 06:31:17,609 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: pre1[4,7],pre2[-1,-1],pre3[7,7],pre4[8,7],r2[13,5] C:  R: r5[-1,-1]
2014-07-07 06:31:17,661 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete`

How would you suggest to debug the issue starting from here?
Do you think that given the data size the number of machine is reasonable?
I was really expecting to finish the job in that amount of time.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have access to the JobTracker so that you can monitor in detail each task? You should be able to get through 5 GB in 1 hour on your own machine, let alone 10 Amazon instances...

Comment: I can see the `task-attempts` log folder. 
Inside it I have all the details of the different tasks going on (http://cl.ly/image/122g2G3x221X).

Each of them looks like this ===>

Opening 's3n://path/to/log/access.log.22' for reading
[...]
Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: pre1[4,7],pre2[-1,-1],pre3[7,7],pre4[8,7],r2[13,5] C:  R: r5[-1,-1]
2014-07-07 06:33:09,202 INFO [Thread-5] amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsUtil: instance controller state completed
2014-07-07 06:33:09,809 INFO [Thread-5] amazon.emr.metrics.MetricsSaver: EMR metrics is disabled

Comment: I've seen similar behavior when running over a large number of small files in S3 (the files do not get allocated equally across mappers). Do you see the same behavior when you copy files from S3 to HDFS (you can combine small files this way) using s3distcp (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge amount of log files, I could imagine that the processing may be slow. In that case you could proceed by combining them before placing them on HDFS. The general amount of 5GB should not be a problem for a simple parsing script on that kind of hardware.

The general next step for this kind of situation would be to make the problem smaller.

1. Does it work on amazon, if you just feed it a few small files instead of 5 GB.
2. If so, how does the runtime increase if you first give it 1%, then 2%, then 10%?
3. If it does not work, what happens if you make your parsing function trivial, or skip it alltogether?